# How to allow users to see previously sent messages in a node.js chat app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am making a chat app using node.js and noticed that when a user logs out and then logs back in, they can no longer see any of the previously sent messages.

What is the best way to go about allowing users to see all past messages (or maybe up to a certain number)?

Answer (score -1):

To see previous messages they have to be stored in database, you can use MongoDB to store the messages and display them.One other unconventional way would be to store messages in text file and display them.